# Material.io web with webpack error "Can't find stylesheet to import"

Tags: webpack, sass, material-components-web

I tried using matrial.io with webpack, just as described in [material.io's getting started](https://material.io/develop/web/docs/getting-started/) with the following configurations:

**webpack.config.js** --> exactly like [example](https://material.io/develop/web/docs/getting-started/)

```
const autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer');

module.exports = {
    entry: ['./app.scss'],
    mode: 'development',
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'file-loader',
                        options: {
                            name: 'bundle.css',
                        },
                    },
                    {loader: 'extract-loader'},
                    {loader: 'css-loader'},
                    {
                        loader: 'postcss-loader',
                        options: {
                            plugins: () => [autoprefixer()]
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader',
                        options: {
                            sassOptions: {
                                implementation: require('sass'),
                                includePaths: ['./node_modules'],
                            },
                        },
                    }
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
};
```

**app.scss** --> exactly like the [example](https://material.io/develop/web/components/ripples/)

```
@use "~@material/ripple";

.test {
  @include ripple.surface;
  @include ripple.radius-bounded;
  @include ripple.states;
}
```

**package.json**

```
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "build": "webpack --config=webpack.config.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "autoprefixer": "^9.7.4",
        "css-loader": "^3.4.2",
        "extract-loader": "^5.0.1",
        "file-loader": "^6.0.0",
        "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
        "sass": "^1.15.2",
        "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
        "webpack": "^4.42.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "material-components-web": "^4.0.0"
    }
}
```

However, when I run `npm run build` I get the following error:

```
ERROR in ./app.scss
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):

@use "~@material/ripple";
^
      Can't find stylesheet to import.
  ╷
1 │ @use "~@material/ripple";
  │ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  ╵
  stdin 1:1  root stylesheet
      in /path-to-file/app.scss (line 1, column 1)
 @ multi ./app.scss main[0]
```

I also tried gulp but I was getting the same error.

**Any idea how I can make it work?**

I also created a repo for that. You can clone:
https://github.com/nazari-dev/material.io

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm adding an alternative answer with a different mindset and fewer steps, in this way:

1. I just update `sass` and `sass-loader` and definitely `material-components-web` to the latest versions. so at the end of this update, your *package.json* is like below:

   ```
   {
     "private": true,
     "scripts": {
       "build": "webpack --config=webpack.config.js"
     },
     "devDependencies": {
       "autoprefixer": "^9.7.4",
       "css-loader": "^3.4.2",
       "extract-loader": "^5.0.1",
       "file-loader": "^6.0.0",
       "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
       "sass": "^1.26.3",
       "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
       "webpack": "^4.42.0",
       "webpack-cli": "^3.3.11"
     },
     "dependencies": {
       "material-components-web": "^5.1.0"
     }
   }
   ```
2. Then in the `app.scss` file use mixins like following:

   ```
   @use "~@material/ripple/index";

   .test {
     @include index.surface;
     @include index.radius-bounded;
     @include index.states;
   }
   ```

**Then by the `npm run build` command you have a successful build**, in fact, you missed match the latest versions of `sass`, `sass-loader` and `material-components-web`, then you used the latest docs and they have some conflicts with each other and this causes to your error.

, In this second solution, I saw a weird thing, when I write [the example](https://material.io/develop/web/docs/getting-started/) exactly look like the given link the `@use '@material/button';` works well and the parser could see the `_index.scss` inside the `node_modules/@material/button` folder. but when I switch to your need, I mean `@use "@material/ripple";` exactly like [this link](https://material.io/develop/web/components/ripples/), the parser **couldn't** see the `_index.scss` inside the `node_modules/@material/ripple` folder and undoubtedly, it comes from the `package.json` of the ripple module. because in the `package.json` of `ripple` module there is `"main": "dist/mdc.ripple.js"` and `"module": "index.js"` which I don't know why the author declares it, we're forced to use `@use "~@material/ripple/index";` just for this declarations.

I leave [an issue](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web/issues/5734) for this weird thing.

Comment: Thank you for the response. It fixed the issue. You can also see it here: https://github.com/nazari-dev/material.io/tree/fixed

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you don't obey the [instruction](https://material.io/develop/web/docs/getting-started/) of getting started with material.io, but if you followed you wouldn't be a success. based on the open [issue](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/sass-loader/issues/804) and some other issues the [@material](https://www.npmjs.com/org/material) has a lot of issues. Especially it has issues with `sass-loader`. definitely, I offer you don't use it and seek to find a better solution.

But, for the current build error follow these steps to have a successful build:

1. Build a custom importer functions and put it in the top of your webpack configuration file:

   ```
   function tryResolve_(url, sourceFilename) {
       try {
           return require.resolve(url, {paths: [path.dirname(sourceFilename)]});
       } catch (e) {
           return '';
       }
   }

   function tryResolveScss(url, sourceFilename) {
       const normalizedUrl = url.endsWith('.scss') ? url : `${url}.scss`;
       return tryResolve_(normalizedUrl, sourceFilename) ||
           tryResolve_(path.join(path.dirname(normalizedUrl), `_${path.basename(normalizedUrl)}`),
               sourceFilename);
   }

   function materialImporter(url, prev) {
       if (url.startsWith('@material')) {
           const resolved = tryResolveScss(url, prev);
           return {file: resolved || url};
       }
       return {file: url};
   }
   ```
2. Change the `sass-loader` config on the webpack configuration file just like below:

   ```
   {
       loader: 'sass-loader',
       options: {
           importer: materialImporter,
       },
   }
   ```
3. Update the `sass` npm package by using the following command, it should be `"sass": "^1.26.3"`:

   ```
   npm update sass
   ```
4. Remove the `~` from `app.scss` file. because we use our costume importer function so this tilde cannot resolve by our new importer function. and then directly import the `_mixins.scss` partial file. so we have:

   ```
   @use "@material/ripple/mixins";
   ```
5. Instead of including `surface` by `ripple.surface` you should import it directly from the `mixins` partial file. I don't know why the [example](https://material.io/develop/web/components/ripples/) write it like `@include ripple.surface;` and import the **ripple** from `@use "@material/ripple";`! because of the `_ripple.scss`file doesn't exist and accordingly the **surface** doesn't exist too. I read the [@use doc](https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/use) of sass and understand the *@use* could be used when the sass file existed, so I think importing like [this example](https://material.io/develop/web/components/ripples/) is not for a use-case like your [re-production](https://github.com/nazari-dev/material.io).

   ```
   @include mixins.mdc-ripple-surface;
   ```
6. Finally, your `app.scss` file should be like below:

   ```
   @use "@material/ripple/mixins";

   .test {
     @include mixins.mdc-ripple-surface;
     @include mixins.mdc-ripple-radius-bounded;
   }
   ```

In the end, the `npm run build` command runs successfully.